# "-in" term in equation

Tags: terminology

I found the following equation in an article and I don't understand what the "in" term means. It's not a variable nor a parameter.

[image]

The article can be found in http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2980374/#FD4
(equation 15).

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to link to the article.

Comment: inch? I really have no clue without context.

Comment: Or at least mention the topic of the article.  Does the equation have a name; are any of the terms identified.  What are $\sf P_E$, and $\sf V_{A_{Rel}}$ ? Give us something to work with so someone might recognise it. @Alejandro

Comment: Right. I posted the article.

Comment: Perhaps it is a typo and they meant "ln" for the logarithm – just a wild guess.

Comment: I can find nothing that defines it. You will probably have to look up the article by Smith and Stamenovic that the paper is pulling this from.

Comment: @MartinR - good guess! that is likely the answer - particularly as they are quoting this result from another paper.

Comment: Right.  Elastic pressure. It's a typographical error.  That curve is a log relation,  They meant $\ln$ , the natural log.

Comment: Looks like typo for $-ln$

Comment: The original article can't be read online. I will test with logarithm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Martin said in a comment and as was agreed upon by other commenters, the authors almost certainly meant to write "$\ln$". That makes sense, given that they say that the equation is the curve fit of the graph directly above it, which looks like a logarithmic fit if I've ever seen one.